# Extract entire string up to the last delimiter

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I need to query that that contains information about products. Product names look like this:

```
Samsung TV 1500 - LED - USA
Sony 19.2/2.12/12V3/320/AE-EL:SILVER-ITA
```

Here is what I am using:

```
SELECT
 TRIM( 
    LEFT(
         a.description, 
        (LENGTH( a.description) - LOCATE('-', a.description)) 
    )
)
FROM products
```

But it gives `Samsung TV 1500` not `Samsung TV 1500 - LED`.
All I need is to remove the last `-USA`, `-IND` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the value so that the last occurrence becomes the first.

```
SELECT
 TRIM( 
    LEFT(
         a.description, 
        (LENGTH( a.description) - LOCATE('-', REVERSE(a.description))+1) 
    )
)
FROM products
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works, but assumes you have exactly two sub-fields:

```
mysql> SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Samsung TV 1500 - LED - USA', '-', 2));
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Samsung TV 1500 - LED - USA', '-', 2)) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Samsung TV 1500 - LED                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You might also want to consider using JSON to store these sub-fields instead of using a hyphen-separated string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the reverse method to get the last occurrence.

```
CREATE TABLE products (description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (description));
INSERT INTO products (description) VALUES ('Samsung TV 1500 - LED - USA');
SELECT TRIM(LEFT(a.description, (LENGTH( a.description) - locate('-', reverse(a.description))))) FROM products as a;
```